# how to make comma separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my table structure

```
    create table #t(PK int,col1 varchar(10),col2 varchar(10))
  insert into #t values(1,'A','a'),(2,'B','b'),(3,'C','c'),(4,'A','d'),(5,'A','e'),(6,'B','f'),(88,'F','l'),(7,'C','g'),(8,'C','h'),(9,'D','k')
```

output column has to look like this

```
col1    col2
A          a,d,e
B          b,f
C          c,g,h
D          k
F          l
```

How'd i get such an output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop table #t
create table #t(PK int,col1 varchar(10),col2 varchar(10))
insert into #t values(1,'A','a'),(2,'B','b'),(3,'C','c'),(4,'A','d'),(5,'A','e'),(6,'B','f'),(88,'F','l'),(7,'C','g'),(8,'C','h'),(9,'D','k')

select col1,SUBSTRING(d.col2,1,len(d.col2)-1)col2
from 
(
    select distinct col1 from #t
)a
cross apply(
select [col2]+',' from #t B where A.col1=B.col1
for xml path('')
)d (col2)
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/31937)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select distinct t.[col1],
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + t1.col2
         from yourtable t1
         where t.[col1] = t1.[col1]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,'') department
from yourtable t;
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc05b/1)